# Ruby: how do I pass the element and its index from an array?

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
arr = [1,2,"car"]

arr.each do |e|
  puts e
end

#=> 1
    2
    car
```

But how do I make a "put e" that also shows its index number?

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = [1,2,"car"]

arr.each_with_index() do |e,i|
  puts "#{e} is at index #{i}"
end
# >> 1 is at index 0
# >> 2 is at index 1
# >> car is at index 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1,2,"car"]

arr.each_with_index do |e, index|
  puts index, e
end
```

Answer (score -2):

To get only index:

```
arr = [1,2,"car"]
arr.each_index do |index|
  puts index
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with this ans? before vote down pls. share your views, so that it can be improved.

Comment: The OP wants both, the element and the index, your answer only solves half the problem

Comment: @suvankar your code will work.. Just do `puts index,arr[index]`.